# Reduce a List of tuples in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a List of tuples : `val re = List((2,3), (3,5), (2,4))`

I'm attempting to reduce this List so that each second parameter of the tuple is summed.

So `List((2,3), (3,5), (2,4))`

becomes

```
List((2,7) , (3,5))
```

I've been researching the Scala Spark examples : https://spark.apache.org/examples.html such as word count :

```
val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                 .map(word => (word, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

But when I try something similar on my collection I receive error :

```
scala> re.reduceByKey(_ + _)
<console>:13: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of List[(Int, Int)]
              re.reduceByKey(_ + _)
                 ^
```

How can I use reduce function on a List of tuples ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import implicit methods to bring PairRDDFunctions from SparkContext in scope and then:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

def tuples: RDD[(Int, Int)] = ???

type Sum = Int

val seqOp: (Sum, Int) => Sum = _ + _    
val combOp: (Sum, Sum) => Sum = _ + _

tuples.aggregateByKey(0)(seqOp, combOp)
```

I added type 'Sum' for clear distinction between Int used as a Key and Int used as a value

reduceByKey also works after PairRDDFunctions is available